# synchronized object's ivar across object hierarchy?

Tags: objective-c, synchronization

I wanted to keep a tally, in an ivar, in a root block which is shared to its lineage. The resulting value is not used in siblings, but a different object lineage.  The scalar is

```
@property (assign) NSUInteger ceil;
```

and normaly synthesized as

```
@synthesize ceil;
```

but only accessed (for update), via its housing object being synthesized:

```
- (NSUInteger)nextCeil
{
    NSUInteger nextCeil = 0;
    //  The root (date) agenda keeps the master. When we fetch
    //  another ceil we clone it for our use as well. Later we
    //  can access this value in case we need to diagnose.
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        //  If we have a root go up there for value
        if (root)
        {
            nextCeil = [root nextCeil];
        }
        else
        {
            nextCeil = ++ceil;
        }
    }
    return nextCeil;
}
```

My question is, given the environment of multiple threads is, is this safe / correct?  I have so far not run into any issues.

The design history is that this root is central for its siblings which have a date reference, the root being a day centric, while siblings are time centric. For uniqueness a tally was needed per day, distributed to the time centric object but not stored there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's is probably OK, but Apple appears to leave room for doubt in their [Thread Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) by including the note:

> **Note**: Most types of locks also incorporate a memory barrier to ensure that any preceding load and store instructions are completed before entering the critical section

Most? If this concerns you use the atomic increment with barrier covered in the same document.

Of course none of these approaches are safe unless you use them for all accesses to your ivar.

HTH

Comment: Yeah that's the only door provided to modify, thanks.